# How to set Remember Token while registering the user in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a CMS app where the user has to register first.

I am remembering them via `Auth::viaRemember()` which uses `remember_token` from database.

But how do I set this `remember_token` field in the database while registering the user?

Comment: I think `remember_token` is for login not for registration

Comment: First time guards ask for credentials and if you set remember_token. Next time check for token instead credentials.

Answer (score 0):

at backend first you have to insert the user and after inserting the user you can login user manually using

`if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], $remember)) {
    // The user is being remembered...
}`